# How to integrate Django and Cygwin?

Tags: python, django, cygwin

I have a Windows box with cygwin, python and django installed.

Now I want to run django-admin, but when I do I get the error:

```
$ django-admin.py
c:\Python26\python.exe: can't open file '/usr/bin/django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you mind me being a bit cheeky? Why are you running Python from cygwin? You don't need to; you can just run Python/Django natively under Windows. You probably have a good reason for this, so...sorry.

Comment: I had the exact same need. My production server runs debian but it's convenient (read faster) to develop on my local machine with a dev/test server which I can easily set up and tear down.

Comment: @Jon Cage - That sounds like a good use for VirtualBox.

Comment: @Jason Baker - That's certainly an option I had considered but after a lot of fiddling I have it working in cygwin without the need for a virtual machine.

Answer (score 5):

From [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs)

> For Windows users, who do not have symlinking functionality available, you can copy django-admin.py to a location on your existing path or edit the PATH settings (under Settings - Control Panel - System - Advanced - Environment...) to point to its installed location.

hope this helps

Comment: The django_admin.py is on the path.
It starts with:
#!c:\Python26\python.exe
and bash sees and loads the file.
Then the python.exe is given a bad path (cygwin path, not windows path) to the django_admin.py file. :-(

Comment: You need to use the cygwin version of python if you're running under cygwin.. as far as I can tell this is unavoidable :-(

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the exact same problem. I've found that if you already have the windows version of python installed, it seems to get priority over the cygwin version. I solved the problem by editing /etc/profile and changed:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:$PATH
```

...to:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:
```

...which I *think* stops cygwin from adding the normal windows path. Once you've got that working, download django into some directory, move into that directory and type:

```
python setup.py install
```

I was having problems to begin with because I had omitted the 'python' bit at the start

Answer (score 1):

As for the step on how to start your django in cygwin

first open your windows command prompt
then register the python environment by doing this:

```
Path %path%;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts
```

then now go to the installation folder of your cygwin

```
cd C:\cygwin
```

then run the **cygwin.bat** like this:

```
C:\cygwin>cygwin.bat    <enter>
```

then cygwin will open, and type **python** to see if it now working

```
$ python
```

Voila we are done!

Answer (score 0):

Sort of sounds like the windows version of Python is trying to run instead of the cygwin one. What happens if you type this:

```
$ python django-admin.py
```

Here I'm assuming

```
$ which python
```

Finds the cygwin version of python (which will be something like /usr/bin/python).

You may also try (temporarily) uninstalling the windows version of python and use only cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Help us help you. Is there a reason why you are running the windows python interpreter (c:\Python26\python.exe) as oppose to the cygwin python interpreter (/usr/bin/python.exe)? That could be your problem. So to troubleshoot that, you might consider removing the windows native interpreter or simply making sure the cygwin path is listed before the c:\Python26 path in the windows global PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Add the location of your django/bin folder (or wherever else you keep django-admin.py) to your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Like Brian mentioned you are running the Windows version of Python which won't work with the Cygwin installation.

A word of warning. When I first started using Django, I tried installing it in Cygwin and had a variety of problems and ended up switching to the regular Windows version of Python. Unfortunately, I didn't document all my issues, but I remember some of them had to do with the database libraries. Anyway, that was a few months ago when I knew less about Django than I do now. Maybe the problems I ran into have been solved and perhaps now that I know more I could get it to work, but running Django on Cygwin does seem to be the road less traveled. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the **django-admin.py** to the current location you are working on for e.g

on Cygwin:

```
<root>/projects/
```

on your windows directory it will look like this:

```
C:\cygwin\home\<your computer name>\projects\
```

once you copy the file, you can create your project by typing this command:

```
$ python django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

and that's all - you have completed your first project using the Cygwin linux-like environment.

Answer (score 0):

Add two lines to `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files (view their difference [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc)). You can find them in `C:\cygwin\home\[username]`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/python2.7
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/cygdrive/c/python2.7/Lib/site-packages
```

Hope this helps