# Cygwin - ImportError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, cygwin

I have been searching for hours for a solution to this. I already have django installed but whenever I attempt to use a manage.py command, I get an importError: No module named 'django'. django is installed in  c:\python34\lib\site-packages, but my python 3.4.3 path is '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages'. I am not sure how to change the path or how to move django into another folder. Anyone have any tips on how to get this to work?

Comment: Try appending c:\python34\lib\site-packages into your PYTHONPATH environment variable. export PYTHONPATH=$(PYTHONPATH):c:\python34\lib\site-packages  You might want to massage this path a little bit under cygwin /cygdrive/c/what-not

Comment: Yup that worked perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your add PATH, PYTHONPATH to `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51978188/5188531).